# Newline "\n" not Working when Writing a .txt file Python

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files, file-writing

```
for word in keys:
    out.write(word+" "+str(dictionary[word])+"\n")
    out=open("alice2.txt", "r")
    out.read()
```

For some reason, instead of getting a new line for every word in the dictionary, python is literally printing \n between every key and value.
I have even tried to write new line separately, like this...

```
for word in keys:
    out.write(word+" "+str(dictionary[word]))
    out.write("\n")
    out=open("alice2.txt", "r")
    out.read()
```

What do I do?

Comment: Are you sure your words dont contain `\n` in them, as a side note why are you not closing your file before opening another?

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. You're writing then opening?

Comment: Are you visualizing the result in the python shell or in the txt file (using a standard text editor), I'm pretty sure the result will be as you expect in the latter...

Comment: Why are you re-opening your file, and how do you expect to write to it when you reach the next `word` in `keys` when you've opened it in `r` mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you do:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/file', 'w') as f:
...    for i in range(10):
...       f.write("Line {}\n".format(i))
...
```

And then you do:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/file') as f:
...    f.read()
... 
'Line 0\nLine 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5\nLine 6\nLine 7\nLine 8\nLine 9\n'
```

It *appears* that Python has just written the literal `\n` in the file. It hasn't. Go to the terminal:

```
$ cat /tmp/file
Line 0
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
```

The Python interpreter is showing you the invisible `\n` character. The file is fine (in this case anyway...) The terminal is showing the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) of the string. You can `print` the string to see the special characters interpreted:

```
>>> s='Line 1\n\tLine 2\n\n\t\tLine3'
>>> s
'Line 1\n\tLine 2\n\n\t\tLine3'
>>> print s
Line 1
    Line 2

        Line3
```

---

Note *how* I am opening and (automatically) closing a file with `with`:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
  # do something with a write only file
# file is closed at the end of the block
```

It appears in your example that you are mixing a file open for reading and writing at the same time. You will either confuse yourself or the OS if you do that. Either use `open(fn, 'r+')` or first write the file, close it, then re-open for reading. It is best to use a `with` block so the close is automatic.